# Getting strange googleapi Err 400 message connecting to postgresql CloudSQL instance

Tags: postgresql, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I´m getting a strange Err 400 missing project parameter when trying to connect to a CloudSQL instance using the **cloud_sql_proxy** mechanism

I have a GCE project with a working CloudSQL postgres database, my apps on the compute api can use it and I can do regular psql from any of the VM I have configured inside my GCE project.

However, when I try to connect to the database from my laptop using the cloud_sql_proxy I get this strange error.

I´m following to the letter this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-proxy#install

So, following that documentation I have:

1. CloudSQL enabled and working as I commented
2. Proxy Installed
3. I have a service account created as the documentation say with Cloud SQL Admin role as follows:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "my-proyect-21432",
  "private_key_id": "<hidden intentionally>",
  "private_key": "<hidden intentionally>",
  "client_email": "cloudsql-serviceaccount@my-proyect-21432.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "<hidden intentionally>",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/cloudsql-serviceaccount@my-proyect-21432.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

4. I started the **cloud_sql_proxy** successfully as follows:

```
user@hostname:~$ ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=db1=tcp:15432 -credential_file=my-proyect-21432.json
2019/05/29 10:17:25 Rlimits for file descriptors set to {&{8500 65536}}
2019/05/29 10:17:25 using credential file for authentication; email=cloudsql-serviceaccount@my-proyect-21432.iam.gserviceaccount.com
2019/05/29 10:17:25 Listening on 127.0.0.1:15432 for db1
2019/05/29 10:17:25 Ready for new connections
```

5. And finally I launch the **psql** client as follows:

```
psql "host=127.0.0.1 port=15432 sslmode=disable dbname=db1 user=dbuser"
```

I see on the **cloud_sql_proxy** the following error:

```
2019/05/29 10:17:33 New connection for "db1"
2019/05/29 10:17:34 couldn't connect to "db1": googleapi: Error 400: Missing parameter: project., required
```

And on the client side I'm getting:

```
psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

At this point I should get my **psql** client connected successfully and I can´t find anything about this error online or in the google's documentation

I have no clue where I need to set a **project** parameter, I tried crazy places like on the psql side with **-v** or using the url with **?** at the end with no luck, I also tried on the cloud_sql_proxy side using the **-projects** flag, also with no luck.

---

### EDIT: New findings!!!

I think I'm close to solve this, the first setup I did (as commented above) was on my windows pc that I use at home, today I'm at the office and I decided to replicate all of that using macos, I don't think that the OS matter at all, the interesting thing is that I replicated all and founded a small thing that make me to move forward

So, I started again and execute points 1., 2., 3., 4. and wait? the documentation states that the **instances string** is as follows: **myproject:us-central1:myinstance** NOT what I originally wrote, so I changed that and start having a more reasonable error:

I started **cloud_sql_proxy** make the connection with **psql** and got this:

```
user@hostname:~$ ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=my-proyect-21432:us-east1:db1=tcp:15432 -credential_file=my-proyect-21432.json
2019/05/30 14:13:25 Rlimits for file descriptors set to {&{8500 65536}}
2019/05/30 14:13:25 using credential file for authentication; email=cloudsql-serviceaccount@my-proyect-21432.iam.gserviceaccount.com
2019/05/30 14:13:25 Listening on 127.0.0.1:15432 for db1
2019/05/30 14:13:25 Ready for new connections

<< when I run psql>>

2019/05/30 14:14:08 New connection for "my-proyect-21432:us-east1:db1"
2019/05/30 14:15:24 couldn't connect to "my-proyect-21432:us-east1:db1": dial tcp 10.26.112.3:3307: connect: operation timed out
```

My db1 instance has only the private IP 10.26.112.3

I started to look for that error around the internet and found a sugestion to allow incoming traffic to 3307 port:

[Cannot Connect by Cloud SQL Proxy from Cloud Shell By Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290972/cannot-connect-by-cloud-sql-proxy-from-cloud-shell-by-proxy)
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/164

So I added the following rule:

```
allow-cloudsqlproxy | Ingress | Apply to all | IP Ranges 0.0.0.0/0 | tcp,udp 3307 | allow | default | 1000
```

But that didn't make any difference because after that I'm still getting the same error message :(

---

### EDIT: from a VM on the same project

I created a VM on that project and replicate all this, I was able to connect, no connection refused on port 3307 message.

I have no idea who is blocking that traffic...

Comment: see my answer here
[sackoverflow sql proxy auth 400 bad request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085467/cloud-sql-proxy-error-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidde/71209611#71209611)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently the **cloud_sql_proxy** does not work if your db instance **only has a private ip** address, I had to add a public one so the proxy server had access to my instance.

I understand certain limitations but if Google provides a **cloud_sql_proxy** it should support all customer cases, I mean, I´m using the default network, that network is managed by google, the network should allow somehow the Proxy Server to reach my db instances.. I don't know ...

The second I added the **public IP** the second it started working ... but I honestly don't want a public IP on my db instances.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for keeping us updated with your findings. I encountered the same problem. I just solved it—your first edit tipped me off.

While following the google CloudSQL documentation process for connecting to CloudSQL from an external application, I started the proxy like this:

```
`./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<instance_name>=tcp:5433`
```

It didn't let me connect. I was receiving this error

```
`couldn't connect to "xxxxxxx": googleapi: Error 400: Missing parameter: project., required`
```

After reading your edit I modified the command to use the entire instance name as stated on the instance details page, and it worked. This is the new command that got it working.

```
`./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=myproject:us-central1:instancename=tcp:5433`
```

I hope this saves someone a few hours.

Comment: Thank you for for this! For passers by here's a link to the docs https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy#tips

Answer (score 1):

Actually cloudsql-proxy does work when your Cloud SQL instance has only an internal IP address. In this scenario you use private services access to establish the connection between the cloudsql-proxy and the Cloud SQL instance. It is also recommended to execute the proxy using the option --ip_address_types=PRIVATE to force it to use the internal IP instead the public when connecting to the Cloud SQL instance.

Look [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy#private-ip) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip) for more details.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The first link says, "To connect to a Cloud SQL instance using private IP, the proxy must be on a resource with access to the same VPC network as the instance." So I guess this means it's impossible to use the proxy to connect to a database instance that has only a private IP from your local machine?

Comment: I just tried it from another server I have access to (a VPS running on Linode), where I temporarily disabled the firewall. Same issue that I had locally.

Answer (score 0):

However trivial it may sound, for me an update from `gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.05` to `gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:latest`* of the CloudSQL proxy image in Kubernetes deployment file resolved the problem.

*Bearing in mind the final comments of the question author, I believe it may be a bug of CloudSQL that requires you to trigger something that will completely restart its instance. This is just speculation though.*

---

* I tried this on version `1.16`. If you are unsure about the stability of futures releases, you can specify the version instead of the `latest` tag.